# Random value with CCCallFunc: value not updated?

Tags: objective-c, random, cocos2d-iphone

Would you know how to change the value of flashPosX ? A "log" in changeFlashPosX works fine, but the value does not change:

```
-(void)changeFlashPosX{
    CCLOG(@"change");
    flashPosX = random() % 300;
    CCLOG(@"rando : %f", flashPosX);
}

-(void)animFlash{
    CCScaleTo *to1 = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.2 scale:1];
    CCScaleTo *to0 = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.6 scale:0];
    CCMoveTo *moveTo = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.1 position:ccp(flashPosX, flash.position.y)];
    CCCallFunc *callChange = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(changeFlashPosX)];
    CCSequence *seq = [CCSequence actions:to1, to0, callChange, moveTo, nil];
    //CCAction *repeatSeq = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:seq];
    CCRepeatForever *repeatSeq = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:seq];
    [flash runAction:repeatSeq];
}
```

The output :

```
rando : 164.000000
change
rando : 217.000000
change
rando : 241.000000
change
rando : 75.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CCMoveTo *moveTo = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.1 position:ccp(random() % 300, flash.position.y)];
```

If it works, then the issue is either with the scope and/or retention of your `flashPosX` variable, or with the routine loop called by the `CCSequence`.

Also, try this:

```
CCRepeatForever *repeatSeq = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:seq];
```

Comment: by the way, you might want to use `arc4random()` instead of `random`; also you mentioned you are logging, but please show where and the results of hte log

Comment: thanks, so i edited my post, the output is correct with the right value, but the "flash" stays at the exact same position in the x-axis... It is repeated forever, the CCLOG works fine - the random value changes each time the function is called, but not the position of the animation...

Comment: Others (including myself) have found actions to not always be the best except for one-off events. cocos is not a perfect library. It is much more reliable to use the `update` method built into Cocos to adjust the position of something you need continuously changing than it is to rely on actions to do this. I'd move your routine into `update` and adjust the x position of the sprite by a small random number every frame.

Comment: additionally I'd recommend using repeatForever events with simple single actions than with sequences.

Comment: thanks, okay, but the position should not be "constant", it has to be a random number. Do you have by any chance any other idea? i am a bit stuck with my flash animation here. But otherwise, thanks for your answers, i really appreciate.

Comment: that's entirely fine, just increment your X coordinate by a random number in your update method. this is very common way of programming independently moving sprites in Cocos. the X increment should be quite small, since the update runs many times per second

Comment: thanks andrewx, okay i found out how to fix it, with a simple CCCallFunc to the same method, instead of "CCRepeat...", thanks for your help!